# MIPS emulator cannot run mips executable due to invalid ELF header

Tags: assembly, mips, qemu, emulation

So i wanted to start writing some mips assembly, and setup my tools.
I am using Arch Linux, and installed cross-mipsel-linux-gnu-gcc and binutils from the user repository which works great and successfully compiles my simple test program into a mipsel binary.

I didn't want any fancy gui or the like for my emulation, and went for qemu. This is were i have issues. When i try to run my executable with `qemu-mipsel ./test`, qemu simply replies `./test: Invalid ELF image for this architecture`.

The first thing i though was "Can qemu really just run base mips binaries like that? That seems almost like magic, this can't be right.", so i started googling if it was actually possible and [found a tutorial on how to to similar compilation for a openwrt but with C code](http://lauri.xn--vsandi-pxa.com/tub/computer-architecture/building-mips-toolchain.html)<, and after looking at that tutorial it seems like my steps should work too.

This is my command for compiling the assembly, clean and simple 
`mipsel-linux-gnu-as test.asm -o test; chmod +x ./test`

Here's the output of the `file` command
`./test: ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, MIPS, MIPS-I version 1 (SYSV), not stripped`

Here's the output of `readelf -a ./test`

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              REL (Relocatable file)
  Machine:                           MIPS R3000
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x0
  Start of program headers:          0 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          164 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x1000, o32, mips1
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           0 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         0
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         9
  Section header string table index: 6

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS        00000000 000040 000010 00  AX  0   0 16
  [ 2] .data             PROGBITS        00000000 000050 000000 00  WA  0   0 16
  [ 3] .bss              NOBITS          00000000 000050 000000 00  WA  0   0 16
  [ 4] .reginfo          MIPS_REGINFO    00000000 000050 000018 18   A  0   0  4
  [ 5] .pdr              PROGBITS        00000000 000068 000000 00      0   0  4
  [ 6] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 000068 00003a 00      0   0  1
  [ 7] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 00020c 000060 10      8   6  4
  [ 8] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 00026c 000001 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings)
  I (info), L (link order), G (group), T (TLS), E (exclude), x (unknown)
  O (extra OS processing required) o (OS specific), p (processor specific)

There are no section groups in this file.

There are no program headers in this file.

There are no relocations in this file.

The decoding of unwind sections for machine type MIPS R3000 is not currently supported.

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 6 entries:
   Num:    Value  Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 
     2: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2 
     3: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 
     4: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 
     5: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    5 

No version information found in this file.
```

Comment: FYI: Debian mips VM for qemu-system-mips at https://people.debian.org/~aurel32/qemu/mips/, the executables from this can be run and with "multiarch" packages can be installed cross platform too.  (and ppc and arm and sh4 too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgotten to link your code. The assembler `as` only produces object file, you need to link it. Presumably you want something like:

```
mipsel-linux-gnu-as test.asm -o test.o
mipsel-linux-gnu-ld test.o -o test
```

If you do it correctly, the `file` command output should include `executable`, such as:

```
ELF 32-bit LSB executable, MIPS, MIPS-I version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I presumed that the as compiler skipped the object stage, but that was stupid of me to assume. Works now, and qemu is awesome!